# How to trim characters from a position to another position in iOS (Objective C)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, nsstring

My problem is, i want to trim away some characters from my string. My string contains xml. So i need to trim characters from an xml opening tag upto its closing tag. How can i do it?

Eg: My string contains the following xml codes.

```
<CategoriesResponse xmlns="https://abc.defg.com/hijk">
    <MainCategories>
        <CatID xsi:type="xsd:int">178</CatID>
        <CatID xsi:type="xsd:int">150</CatID>
        <CatID xsi:type="xsd:int">77</CatID>
        <CatID xsi:type="xsd:int">33</CatID>
        <CatID xsi:type="xsd:int">179</CatID>
    </MainCategories>
<SubCategories>
    //some needed elements should not be trimmed.
</SubCategories>
```

i need to trim from the opening tag `<MainCategories>` to closing tag `</MainCategories>`.
How to do it?? So here my starting character will be `<MainCategories` and ending character will be `/MainCategories>`

Comment: How about NSXMLParser?

Comment: i parse the response in xml parser. it works good. but the problem is the `CatID`s in between the `MainCategory` tags are unwanted. but the `CatIDs` inside `SubCategories` are needed. when i am using `NSXMLParser` all the `CatID`s are parsed. that make me a big mess

Comment: You simply keep a flag that indicates whether you are inside a `MainCategories` tag or not. You can know this from the calls to the delegate `didStartElement` and `didEndElement` methods

Comment: yeah i changed a bit like you said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
NSString *str = @"<CategoriesResponse xmlns=\"https://abc.defg.com/hijk\"><MainCategories><CatID xsi:type=\"xsd:int\">178</CatID><CatID xsi:type=\"xsd:int\">150</CatID><CatID xsi:type=\"xsd:int\">77</CatID><CatID xsi:type=\"xsd:int\">33</CatID><CatID xsi:type=\"xsd:int\">179</CatID></MainCategories><SubCategories></SubCategories>";


NSRange startRange = [str rangeOfString:@"<MainCategories>"];
NSRange endRange = [str rangeOfString:@"</MainCategories>"];
NSString *replacedString = [str stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(startRange.location, (endRange.location+endRange.length)-startRange.location) withString:@""];
NSLog(@"%@",replacedString);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: oh my friend, its in swift. am doing in objective c. i don't know swift.

Comment: oh my god... oh it worked.. it worked. thanks man. if 5 upvotes where possible, i will give you 5. i was screwed up on this

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

```
NSString *strXml=@"<CategoriesResponse xmlns=\"https://abc.defg.com/hijk\"><MainCategories><CatID xsi:type=\"xsd:int\">178</CatID><CatID xsi:type=\"xsd:int\">150</CatID><CatID xsi:type=\"xsd:int\">77</CatID><CatID xsi:type=\"xsd:int\">33</CatID><CatID xsi:type=\"xsd:int\">179</CatID></MainCategories><SubCategories></SubCategories>";

                       strXml=[strXml stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<MainCategories>" withString:@"<MainCategories"];

                       strXml=[strXml stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"</MainCategories>" withString:@"/MainCategories>"];

                       NSLog(@"%@",strXml);
```

Hope it will help :)

Comment: it helped. But actually i was looking to remove those characters (CatID tags)  in between the tags (MainCategories & /MainCategories) including that tag.